# (Strictly) concave/convex function: Increasing / decreasing slope triangle?

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis

I have the following (possibly quick) question. In a paper I am working with, the following conclusions are drawn which I have a hard time to understand. Since they are given without proof, I assume that my mind has not woken up properly yet and I will greatly appreciate help!

First conclusion: Let U be a strictly concave function on $\mathbb{R}^+$ and let $w,z,y>x\geq 0$. Then, the equality $U(y)-U(x) = U(w) - U(z)$ implies due to strict concavity of $U$ that $w-z > y-x$.

- Graphically, I agree with the conclusion but I'd like to have a technical proof.

Second conclusion (converse): For a function $U$ and for all $w,z,y>x\geq 0$ such that $w-z > y-x$ it holds that $U(y)-U(x) = U(w) - U(z)$. Hence, $U$ is concave on $\mathbb{R}^+$.

- In the paper they just write concave. Do they mean strictly concave?
- Again, can anyone show me where the conclusion comes from?

I can see that both conclusions arise from an if and only if statement about (strictly) concave functions, however for some reason I am not able to derive this statement.

If someone knows of a result for convex functions that would obviously help as well.

Thank you for any input, I am just stuck at the moment :(.

Best, 
Martin

Comment: Look for the keyword "three chords lemma" on Webster's book on convexity. It might be helpful

Comment: Thanks for the advice but somehow I can still not figure it out... My main problem is that the three chords lemma considers three strictly ordered variables and in my case I have four variables and the only thing I know is $w,z,y>x\geq 0$. Can you give me another hint?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: I have a new result, can you maybe back up my intuiton?

Comment: That assertion is true.

Comment: Are you sure? The more I think about it, I don't think it is.. e.g. for a strictly convex function take $h_1 >> h_2$, then I think that the left slope triangle may be larger than the right one..

Comment: Awww, right. I didn't realize that $h_1$ might be different from $h_2$, sorry. Of course the assertion is true if $x+h_1\le z$ (three chords lemma, again), but fails in general.

Comment: Well, then, what do you think is the argument to prove the two conclusions? For me, this is clearly not straightforward...